# conditional expectation on uniform RV

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

Consider $X,Y,Z$ independently and identically distributed from uniform distribution $[0,1]$.

I am trying to solve for:

$E(X|X>Y)$.

$E(X|X>Y,X>Z)$.

I am just tyring to understand these simplace cases, so that I can extend to the case of finite $n$ IID uniform random variables, and when I take the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition: $\mathsf E(X\mid X\in A) = \dfrac{\mathsf E(X\,\mathbf 1_{X\in A})}{\mathsf P(A)} = \dfrac{\displaystyle \int_A x~f_{\small X}(x)\,\mathrm d x}{\displaystyle \int_A f_{\small X}(x)\,\mathrm d x}$

So $\mathsf E(X\mid X>Y) =\dfrac{\mathsf E(X\,\mathbf 1_{X>Y})}{\mathsf P(X > Y)}= \dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^1 x\,\mathsf P(Y<x)\,\mathrm d x}{\displaystyle\int_0^1 \mathsf P(Y<x)\,\mathrm d x}=\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^x x\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x}{\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^x 1\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x} = \dfrac{1/3}{1/2} =\dfrac 23\\\displaystyle\phantom{\mathsf P(X_1 {\,=\,}\max\{X_i\}_{i=2}^n) = \int_\Bbb R f_{\small X}(x) \prod_{i=2}^n \mathsf P(x\geqslant X_i)\,\mathrm d x = \int_0^1 x^{n-1}\,\mathrm d x 
\\\mathsf E(X_1\,\mathbf 1_{X_1=\min\{X_i\}_{i=2}^n}) = \int_\Bbb R x\,f_{\small X}(x)\prod_{i=2}^n\mathsf P(x\geqslant X_i)\,\mathrm d x = \int_0^1 x^n\,\mathrm d x
 } $

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please provide an example with my first one, which is $E(X|X>Y)$ using the definition you provided?

Comment: Hi, appreciate you lay out as in definitions. But given, they are from uniform [0,1] with IID, can you provide the actual analytic expression not just in integrals? thanks!

Comment: I obtained $\frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{(1-x)}$.

Comment: $y$ should not appear in the expression after integrating.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it to x. If we have $n$ case, so $N=\{1,...,n\}$ $E(X_i|X_i>X_j \forall j\neq i\in N)$, then I just did the math and want to confirm: would it be $\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1}{(1-X_i)^{n-1}}$? If I did this correctly based on your response, I will chose your response for the contribution to my question and the community. thanks!

Comment: Again, neither $x$ or $X_i$ should not appear in the expression.  The expectations will be constants.

Comment: I am confused. Is the X, Y case correct in my comments?